# Add collison object from a urdf file in moveit

Tags: c++, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a collision object is defined in a urdf file similar to a robot_description,
Is there a way to add collision objects from a urdf file in PlanningScene of moveit?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281826/add-collison-object-from-a-urdf-file-in-moveit/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2018-02-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After doing some research I concluded that, as of now there is no direct method to do so. Thus, for now Im parsing the urdf file using [TinyXml](http://wiki.ros.org/tinyxml) (xml parser).

I get the values of all the necessary attributes of urdf and save them as variables using TinyXml. And then I use those variables in the piece of code where Im defining all the properties of the collision object and adding it to the planning scene.

---

Originally posted by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) with karma: 272 on 2018-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1